# Adding elements to class dynamically

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to work some code. I have a class `IntArr` and I have to add to it elements, but when I passed the size of the class the resize didn't work fine. I can only add an

```
  class IntArr{
     private:
         int * p;
         int size;
         int used;
     public:
         IntArr (int sz);
         IntArr (int sz,int qtty,int *vec);
         ~IntArr();
         void prtArr (void) ;
         void addElement(int xx);
         void addElement(int qtty, int* vec);
 };

 void IntArr:: addElement(int xx){
     if(used+1>size){
         std::vector<int> p;
         size+=6;
         p.resize(size);
     } 
     p[used]=xx;
     used++;
 }
 void IntArr:: addElement(int qtty, int* vec){
     int i;
     i=used;
     std::vector<int> p;
     size+=qtty;
     p.resize(size);
     while(i-used<qtty){
         p[i]=vec[i-used];
         i++;
     }
     used+=qtty;
 } 

void IntArr:: prtArr (void) const{
    using namespace std;
    int i=0;
    cout<<"> Array : ";
    if(!used)
        cout<<"Vacio !!!";
    else
        while(i<used){
            cout<<p[i]<<" ";
            i++;
        }
    cout<<endl;
  }

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 int v_aux[]={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40};
 IntArr A(10,sizeof(v_aux)/sizeof(int),v_aux);
 cout<<" size:"<<A.getSize()<<endl<<" used:"<<A.getUsed()<<endl;
 A.prtArr(); 
 A.addElement(77);
 cout<<" size:"<<A.getSize()<<endl<<" used:"<<A.getUsed()<<endl;
 A.prtArr();
 A.addElement(11);
 cout<<" size:"<<A.getSize()<<endl<<" used:"<<A.getUsed()<<endl;
 A.prtArr();
 A.addElement(8,v_aux);
 cout<<" size:"<<A.getSize()<<endl<<" used:"<<A.getUsed()<<endl;
 A.prtArr();
 PRESS_KEY;
 }
```

The code only works fine to add element 77.

Comment: For god's sake, first read a good book, then use STL :)

Comment: The element `int* p` is not initialized properly - do you want to create an array, dyamically allocate/reallocate, do you want a vector?

Answer (score 0):

On addElement you aren't using the private int *p defined on the class. Every time the addElement method creates a local p std::vector that is destroyed when the method returns.

Comment: And how do I use *p defined in the class? because I tried using this->p, but it didn´t work neither.

Comment: @TobiasPiizzi *How* did you use `this->p`? The class member `p` is declared as a pointer, so you need to manage the memory allocation and deallocation or you could declare it as a `std::vector` (or `std::array` if the size is fixed) and let the standard library do its job.

Comment: You need a better understanding of how pointers and dynamic memory works. A cpp tutorial like [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) would be good.